# Java String.contains() produces duplicate results

Tags: java

I am writing a small program that allows the user to query a database that contains account information.  The database is just a simple text file.  The problem that I have is that my function that is suppose to see if a string contains keywords, sometimes produces duplicate results.

Here is my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    // Clear the text area.
                    textAreaRecords.setText("");

                    String keyword;
                    String[] keywords;
                    String[] parts;
                    String line;
                    String record = "";
                    boolean recordFound = false;

                    // Get keywords from field.
                    keyword = textFieldKeywords.getText();
                    keywords = keyword.split(" ");

                    // Open the file and read form it.
                    try {
                        FileReader fReader = new FileReader("Passwords.txt");
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fReader);

                        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            parts = line.split("\t");

                            for(int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
                                if(parts[0].contains(keywords[i]))
                                    recordFound = true;
                            }

                            if(recordFound) {
                                if(parts.length == 5)
                                    record += parts[0] + "\t" + parts[1] + "\t" + parts[2] + "\t" + parts[3] + "\t" + parts[4] + "\n";
                                else
                                    record += parts[0] + "\t" + parts[1] + "\t" + parts[2] + "\t" + parts[3] + "\n";

                                textAreaRecords.append("Account \t Username \t Password \t Email \t Notes\n\n");
                                textAreaRecords.append(record);
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```

Example of duplicate results...

Database contains:
`BT username password email someOtherNotes
Gmail username password email someOtherNotes
Gmail OtherGmail password email notes`

Keywords provided:
`Gmail`

Program results: 
`BT username password email someOtherNotes
Gmail username password email someOtherNotes`

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you find a hit, you switch `recordFound` to `true`. If the next line is read, the value of `recordFound` is not reset to `false`, meaning from that moment on you will always enter your last `if` statement.

Just add `recordFound = false` as first statement in the `while` loop and your problem should be fixed.

That being said:

- You should be able to solve such a problem yourself. Try using a debugger and try to work out why your program is not doing what you expect it to be doing. Learning how to debug is a necessary skill if you want to program
- Reading files and parsing the whole contents of it should not be done in the `actionPerformed` method. For a small file, this will run quite fast. But once your file becomes bigger, the reading of the file will take more time. During this time, your UI cannot update as you are blocking the UI thread. Consult the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorial for more information.
- When reading files, you need to close the reader once you are finished. This is done either in a `finally` block, or using the try with resources construct available as of JDK7 (see [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more information).

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  That did fix my problem.  I'll look into the other things as well.